# How do we check session in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone advise on how to check if the session is new or same via `javascript`. I need to perform an action if session is same but not sure how to check it ?
Any pointers in this regard would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you referring to a server-side session?

Comment: You'll need to define "session." Are you referring to something specific to the technology you're using (PHP, Java, ASP.Net, ...)? Or the browser's concept of a session?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Check for new/returning visitor or something? Check that on the server and return along with the html for later use in JS.

Comment: what did you mean about the session? are you using the session or cookies?

Comment: Hi @PetrNagy yes, I want to check for new or returning visitor , check that on server and perform the action on the basis of returned value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the browser's concept of a session, you can use `sessionStorage` ([spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-sessionstorage-attribute) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)) to do that. At the point where you need to check:

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem("session")) {
    // You're in an existing session
} else {
    sessionStorage.setItem("session", "yes");
    // You're in a new session
}
```

Comment: I want ti check for the new or returning visitor, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @AmbikaTewari - If you mean, "returning" as it "they were on this page yesterday," it would probably be a use case for `localStorage` rather than `sessionStorage` ([spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)).